# noob Iterator run time error in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator

I'm working on a project in my data stucts book and for some reason even though it's nearly verbatim from what's written I'm still getting a runtime error that I can't identify.

Here is my code:

```
    int main()
{   
    cout << "Enter an expression, to check if its balanced.\n";
    string exp;
    while (getline(cin, exp) && (exp != ""))
    {   
        cout << exp;
        if(is_balanced(exp))
        {
            cout << " is balanced.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " is not balanced.";
        }
        cout << "Enter another expression: \n";
    }
    return 0; 
}

bool is_balanced(const string& expression) // pass reference to the input expression 
{
    //create stack to hold parantheses
    stack<char> s;
    bool balanced = true;  //to hold return value   
    string::const_iterator iter;
    expression.begin(); // sets a read-only iterator at the beginning of the expression
    while (balanced && (iter != expression.end()))  //while 'balanced' and not at end of expression cont. looping
    {
        char nx_ch = *iter;
        if (is_open(nx_ch))
        {
            s.push(nx_ch);
        }
        else if (is_closed(nx_ch))
        {
            if (s.empty())
            {
                balanced = false;
            }
            else
            {
                char tp_ch = s.top(); // if the stack isn't closed set the                    char as tp for comparisson
                s.pop();  // remove top char
                balanced = OPEN.find(tp_ch) == CLOSE.find(nx_ch);
            }
        }
        ++iter;
    }
    if(!s.empty())
    {
        balanced = false; 
        return balanced && s.empty();
    }
    else
    {
        return balanced && s.empty();
    }
}
```

The error occurs at this line: `if(is_balanced(exp))`

In the main and reads:

> Debug Assertion Failed! ... Expression: string iterators incompatible

Everything I've read about the error says it happens when you compare to iterators, but that doesn't make sense if I can't even get it through the constructor. Any help to better understand this would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`string::const_iterator iter;` does not *initialise* the iterator.

Then you are reading its value in `iter != expression.end()`.

The behaviour on doing that is *undefined*.

Did you mean `string::const_iterator iter = expression.begin();`?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you set a variable:

```
string::const_iterator iter;
expression.begin(); // sets a read-only iterator at the beginning of the expression
```

This is how you set a variable:

```
string::const_iterator iter = expression.begin(); // sets a read-only iterator at the beginning of the expression
```

Comment: Oh my God. thank you both so much. I'm such an idiot. I wrote this in word while I was at work and pasted it over this morning chalk full of errors. I didn't even realize I'd moved that in incorrectly. Thank you so much.